# Illuminator vs Copy Editor

Tags: feature-request

I was browsing the badges earlier and I noticed something a little...strange.

**Copy Editor** Requires you to edit 500 posts.

**Illuminator** Requires you to edit and answer 500 posts.

Unless I've missed anything it's completely impossible to get Illuminator without also getting Copy Editor. This is despite them both being gold badges.

Wouldn't it make sense for either Illuminator to require fewer edits (say 300?) or Copy Editor to require more? This way the two badges are similar difficulty to each other and you don't always get one in order to get the other...

Comment: Makes sense to me if there's supposed to be a rule that says that gold badges should be somewhat equally hard to obtain. Illuminator is definitely a whole lot more difficult than copy editor, especially since copy editor counts edits to As and not merely Qs. That said, I'm not sure if it's worth being fussy about the difficulty of obtaining gold badges, especially in hindsight.

Comment: Well I don't think they are supposed to all be the same difficulty (just look at the count of number awarded to see this) but having one that is always going to be achieved on the way to another just seems...strange.

Comment: On a related note, it's also odd how it's possible to have more silver badges than bronze badges. I have 109 silver and 101 bronze on SO. I didn't think that would be possible, but apparently it is.

Comment: Most of your bronze badges you also have the matching silver badges, while you also have some "stand alone" silver badges...so while it does seem a little unusual it's certainly reasonable that it can happen.

Comment: I have 44 silver, 80 bronze. I imagine that's more common.

Comment: I noticed illuminator has the "both actions within 12 hours" requirement? does that mean you have to achieve the 500 threshold for edit and answer almost at the same time? What if I answered 500 posts and then the 500 answers come 13 hours later? Does that mean I permanently lost the chance to win that illuminator?

Answer (score -9):

The Illuminator is the pen ultimate badge for:

Edit and Answering Questions:

```
  Explainer  Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)  415 awarded
  Refiner  Edit and answer 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)  14 awarded
  Illuminator  Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
```

Where as the Copy Editor is just for Editing Posts, which you get points for editing only as long as it is accepted then time frame and upvote doesnt matter.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here. We know where the badge comes from but it's impossible to get Illuminator without also having Copy Editor....in the most specific case possible you receive both badges at the same time (if all you ever do is edit posts you answer).

Comment: @TimB I was trying to say they are for different concepts. But I agree that you will definitely  have the Copy Editor if you have completed the Illuminater